# Using webpack to display content in the html file from the js file

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I'm new to webpack and I would like to display some content to the html file. I am also using firestore to store some data that I would like to show.

I have tried multiple ways that would work in a normal JS file and when i write the script in a separate JS file they display in the browser.

Could anyone give me any advice on where to start with this I've also tried whats written on the webpack site but that also didnt work.

Comment: Two things are really unclear where. (1) What you want to achieve. (2) What you've done to try to achieve that.

Comment: (1) Are you (A) trying to write some JS that manipulates the page at runtime and then pack it using webpack? Or are you (B) trying to write some JS that runs at build time and modifies the source code of HTML page that webpack outputs?

Comment: (2) You say you've "tried whats written on the webpack site". Written where on the webpack site? Link to it! What did you attempt look like? Provide a [mcve]. What was the result of that? Read [ask].